# Бижютерия/бижутерия

Tags: иностранные-слова

Кругом и везде в рекламе пишут "бижутерия". Насколько мне не изменяет память, слово "бижютерия" является заимствованным и пишется через "**ю**". Быть может что-то изменилось в правилах написания этого слова?
P.S. А после слова "память" в моем втором предложении нужна запятая? Спасибо.

Comment: После "может" в третьем предложении должна стоять запятая.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая после "память" нужна. Подобные вводный обороты всегда обособляются.  
Тем более, что грамматически это самостоятельное предложение.

Кстати, исключения даже для трёх слов (парашют, жюри и брошюра) ничем иным как историческим заблуждением объяснить нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Да нет, через Ю пишутся только "парашют", "жюри" и "брошюра". В остальных случаях пишутся все-таки У.

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то, я тоже помню, что в учебнике Это слово относилось к исключениям. В, примерно, 88году, слово "бижутерия" не писалось через "Ю"?

Comment: Не помню такого. Есть Словарь Аванесова, например, - как раз 88 года. Бижутерия.   
да вообще орфография просто так не меняется, единичные случаи уточнения правописания базируются га выводах какого-то авторитетного органа, Орфографической Комиссии, например, в восьмидесятые-девяностые годы никаких ОК не работало.

Answer (score 0):

Информация из Интернета

"Исключения: жюри, брошюра, парашют. Эти слова к нам пришли из французского языка: jury, brochure, parachute. Они появились примерно в начале XIX века. Поскольку это не русские слова, поначалу в русском письме их писали просто латинскими буквами. А затем при замене латинских букв на русские, "u" заменили на "ю" (на французском в этих словах звук "ю"). Кто и когда это сделал - история умалчивает. Любопытно, что французское слово "abat-jour" у нас пишется "абажур". Видимо, поскольку оно пришло в русский язык раньше (XVII век). Тоже и со словом "ажур" (a jour)".

И еще: "более поздние заимствованные из французского языка слова также пишутся (как слышатся) через "ю": амбушюр, жюльен(julienne - нарезка тонкой соломкой, иногда пишут "жульен", но это не правильно и др".

Что же повлияло на ЖЮ, ШЮ - латинское написание или особое ("мягкое") произношение?

Comment: София, информацию "из Интернета" следует маленько фильтровать) Достаточно заглянуть в словарь, где после слов указана их транскрипция и вообще приведены правила произношения французских слов. АбажУр/abat-j**ou**r и ажУр/aj**ou**r произносятся (французами) через  У (**ou**), поэтому и мы так же пишем и произносим.

Comment: Фильтровать надо любую информацию, но даже простая постановка вопроса - это уже неплохо. А вопрос такой: могло ли написание  "u" повлиять на  написание "ю"? И еще: можно ли ЖЮ, ШЮ называть "мягким" произношением, эти слова когда-нибудь произносились "мягко"? Например, в словаре для слова жюри указано произношение ЖУ, мягкое произношение считается архаичным, а вот для брошюры и парашюта указывается только ШУ.Они никогда не имели мягкого произношения?

Comment: Разумеется, французское **u** "виновато" в нашей орфографии) И произносили вначале мягко. Но вопрос-то наш состоит в произношении фр.  **ou**, которое соответствует обычному русскому [у]. А народ зачем-то огород городит вместо простого обращения к словарю фр. слов с транскрипцией...

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению,

1) русские должны писать [обрусевшее] слово "бижутерия" через "у", а почитатели Запада должны писать иностранное слово "бижютерия" через "ю",

2) русские должны писать [обрусевшее] слово "парашут" через "у", а почитатели Запада должны писать иностранное слово "парашют" через "ю".

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю мнение @Галактион: таким образом мы безболезненно выявим пятую колонну в наших рядах! А потом, как следствие: ГосДума - Закон - общественное мнение - пароход с почитателями Запада - ату их! Как в начале 20-х годов!

Comment: *... и чтоб духу ихнего здесь не было!*